# Is Heisenberg's uncertainty principle consistent with Special Relativity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

According to me, an object gains relativistic mass as it approaches the speed of light, and
$$\Delta x \Delta p \ge\frac {\hbar}{2}$$
So objects with speeds close to $c$, should show less uncertainty in position because an object with a small de broglie wavelength is less likely to spread.

$$\lambda = \frac{h}{m_0v}\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$$
$$\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}} \rightarrow 0$$
$$\lambda \rightarrow 0$$

Shouldn't $\Delta x \rightarrow 0$ too?

In short does the uncertainty principle
hold true if  $\Delta p$ is relativistic? Or it only takes non-relativistic mass into the account but is still correct even at speeds close to $c $?

Comment: *"So objects with speeds close to c, should show less uncertainty in position."* Why does that follow? BTW, in special relativity there's no upper bound on momentum.

Comment: also note that $\Delta x \Delta p \geq \hbar/2$, not equal. The uncertainty can be very large both momentum and position

Comment: If a object gains mass, $\Delta x \Delta p$ = $\Delta x m\Delta v$ = $\Delta x \Delta v = h/4\pi m$

Comment: @yu-v thanks for pointing,

Comment: You don't need to bring relativistic mass into it. Momentum in SR is $p=mv\gamma$, where $m$ is the rest mass and $\gamma$ is the Lorentz factor. (If you *insist* on using the [deprecated concept of relativistic mass](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/133395/123208), that equals $m\gamma$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that the "$p$" in $\Delta p$ may not have the properties that you think it has because
$$p= \frac{m_0 v}{\sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2}} $$
where $v$ is the coordinate velocity $dx/dt$ and $m_0$ the rest mass of the particle. Notice that when $v\to c$ then $p \to \infty$!!

This $p$ is what is conserved in collisions and thus has a meaning for *dynamics*, unlike the *kinematic* velocity $v$. In other words, if you do not know $p$ well, you do not know e.g. outcomes of collision experiments well, and that applies even if this corresponds to a very small uncertainty in velocity $\Delta v$.

Now of course, if you reduce $\Delta x$ greatly, the Heisenberg uncertainty principle tells you that $\Delta p >  \hbar/(2\Delta x)$. Since $p$ can attain any value in $(-\infty,\infty)$ without violating relativity (see above), there is no conflict.

Comment: I didn't say that both theories conflict each other, I  I don' understand, if the De Broglie wavelength of an object $\approx 0$ does it imply that  $\Delta x \approx 0$

Comment: @TimCrosby The De Broglie wavelength is the wavelength of a particle with sharp $p$ and thus completely delocalized position. The quasi-classical link between De Broglie wavelength and the Heisenberg uncertainty principle can be made by considering that you are "probing" the particle with a *secondary* particle-wave with momentum $P$. This causes a momentum disturbance to the primary particle $\Delta p \sim P$ and determines its position up to half the wavelength of the probing particle $\Delta x \sim \lambda_{\rm DB}/2 \sim \hbar/(2P)$.

Comment: Then why do macroscopic objects show negligible uncertainty in position and momentum?, I thought that their De Broglie wavelength being so small that it almost looked like one spike.was the reason :(

Comment: @TimCrosby Macroscopic objects show small *relative* uncertainty of momentum compared to their total momentum $\delta p/p \ll 1$, and tiny *relative* uncertainty compared to their size $R$, $\delta x/R \ll 1$. This is absolutely no problem as long as $pR \gg \hbar$. The absolute uncertainties will actually always be *way* larger than the quantum limit in any real experimental context!

Comment: Ty for giving me the correct idea